# How can we get community mods to address meta issues for a beta site if we have no pro-tem mods?

Tags: feature-request, moderation

I'm speaking from the perspective of an HSM user. The community on HSM has been *very* active on HSM meta, and we've addressed a lot of core issues that have come up in the early days of the site. Here are some examples:

- [Do we need MathJax?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-we-need-mathjax?rq=1)
- [What should we name our chatroom?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-should-we-name-our-chatroom?lq=1)
- [Options for the name of this site](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/options-for-the-name-of-this-site?lq=1)
- [Who should our moderators be?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/who-should-our-moderators-be?lq=1)

Yesterday I posted [a question](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180/can-we-get-a-site-name-change-implemented) talking about how we had posted the name-change discussion question over 30 days ago, had come to a clear consensus, and had not gotten results. Even more disturbingly, plannapus said in a comment,

> On that subject (more or less): i flagged the "who should our moderators be" question for it to be made "featured" (as it is supposed to be the case) on November the 14th and my flag is still unanswered... which makes me think that indeed no one with moderator privileges (ie in our case, I guess, community managers) have been around recently.

The MathJax question was dealt with by Robert Cartano (thank you, if you're reading this!), and it's really helped the site. Within about 20 days, we had it.

The others aren't doing so well. The chatroom question is ~36 days old, the name question is ~34 days old, and the moderator question is also ~34 days old.

This question, therefore, is really an extension of the question I posted on HSM meta. I want to use this partly to get the word out to the SE team, but I also want to help our community learn how to communicate better with the community mods for the remaining period before we get site mods of some sort.

**How can we get community mods to address meta issues for a beta site if we have no pro-tem moderators?**

Flagging and using the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) may work, but it's not incredibly direct, and doesn't feel like *we're* doing anything for ourselves.

---

[Pops](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131713/pops) has been doing some work over on HSM, so I think we're going to see some results. I understand that the SE team has been really busy - don't think I'm annoyed - so I completely understand the delay, and I'm really happy about this development.

**Update:**

Mods have been appointed on HSM as of a few days after this question was originally asked (I'm one of them!). We as a community have worked on some of these issues, and appear to have solved the problems that cropped up.

Comment: For the chat room naming, you don't need someone from SE, any moderator on chat (there are 300+ of those) can do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to have a moderator from another site as an active meta user on your site. They can get in touch with SE a bit easier than regular users.

If you don't have a current moderator among your users, you can use the "contact us" link in the footer. This takes a bit longer, but should work as well.

This shouldn't be a big problem usually as the site should have mods by now. I don't know why it hasn't happened for your site by now, but it really should happen very soon. The system isn't really designed to work without mods for long, appointing pro-tem mods is the best solution here.